# Get numerical values txt file using delimiters

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

I have a `txt` file with the following text:

> 5;2;8;3;

I need get the numeric values, using `;` as delimiter, and put them into an array. How could this be achieved?

Comment: `tbl = assert(load('return {'..file_content:gsub(';',',')..'}'))()`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, no need to replace semicolons with commas.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to just use `string.gmatch` to match the numbers:

```
local example = "5;2;8;3;"
for i in string.gmatch(example, "%d+") do
  print(i)
end
```

Output:

```
5                                                                                                                                                                   
2                                                                                                                                                                   
8                                                                                                                                                                   
3
```

A "harder" way with a specific `Split` function:

```
function split(str, delimiter)
    local result = {}
    local regex = string.format("([^%s]+)%s", delimiter, delimiter)
    for entry in str:gmatch(regex) do
        table.insert(result, entry)
    end
    return result
end

local split_ex = split(example, ";")
print(unpack(split_ex))
```

Output:

```
5       2       8       3
```

Have a look at a [sample program here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_lua_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMcUlFRmFjU0pzdWM).

Comment: Thanks a lot for you fastes answer.

Comment: Great, please consider accepting my answer, and perhaps, editing your question to include what you tried (1 example is enough).